# Let $n$ be an integer. Suppose an integer $d$ is a common divisor of the integers $2 n + 3$ and $5 n + 7$.

Tags: proof-verification, logic

Let $n$ be an integer. Suppose an integer $d$ is a common divisor of the integers $2 n + 3$ and $5 n + 7$. Using the common divisor theorem (below), show that $d=\pm 1$.

*If a is a common divisor of b and c , then it divides any integer linear combination of b and c as well*

Answer (score 1):

Since $d|2n+3$ we have $d|10n+15$.

Since $d|5n+7$ we have $d|10n+14$.

So $d|(10n+15)-(10n+14)=1$ so $d=\pm1$

Comment: Thank you. I smacked by head and worked it out just before this was posted, but thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Glad to help! :)